# Blender compositor invert results in incorrect values

Tags: compositing-nodes, color-management

I would like to invert the values in my image in the compositor node, but as you can see from the output shown in the image below, the inverted image appears blown out. You can clearly see this in the almost fully white background.

I want to use the compositor to adjust image textures for pbr materials such as roughness and normal which should be set to non color data in the shader editor as well as base color and emission color which use sRGB.
[image]

I wonder if it is the result of color space  however I haven't found a combination that makes sense or works.
You can see here my current settings for color management in Blender's render properties:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `Invert` node simply inverts the channels with `1 - channel`. But as your input data is in `sRGB`, you need to remove the gamma curve before doing this linear operation and apply it afterwards again (note `0.455` in the image is actually `1/2.2 = 0.454545...`):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What is the significance of the value 2.2?

Comment: It's the common _gamma_ value used in most image file formats to map between linear and sRGB color space. There are plenty of resources if you search for `Gamma correction`.

Comment: @ZakNelson could not edit my comment anymore. In short, the mapping is not linear but with an exponential function, and the exponent is called _gamma_.

Comment: Thank you. I've marked this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Should I keep my view transform in the color management settings as Standard, rather than filmic?

Comment: For me, this has nothing to do with the gamma correction in the question. I see the _Color Management_ purely as a post processing for certain render styles, but others may know better.